# ERROR: Object variable or with block not set

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create macro for an assignment which does the following:

a) Formats the active cell as follows: font type Arial, font size 14, bold font and horizontally centered

b) Deletes the entire row below the active cell

c) Deletes column A regardless of the location of the active cell

However, there is an error thrown when the macro is passed into the grader, which says "Object variable or with block not set". Please refer to the generated VBA below for the steps I took to solve this.

Any help/advice will be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub FormatCells()
'
' FormatCells Macro
'

'
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 14
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub
```

Comment: In which line does the error show?

Comment: Your script does not give an error. At least this part of your full code. Please make two screens about what you would like to see. First and final.

Answer (score 0):

I revised your code, removing the unnecessary parts. I hope it solved your problem.

```
Sub FormatCells()
    'a) Formats the active cell as follows: font type Arial, font size 14, bold font and horizontally centered
    With ActiveCell.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 14
        .Bold = True
    End With
    ActiveCell.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    'b) Deletes the entire row below the active cell
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    'c) Deletes column A regardless of the location of the active cell
    Columns("A:A").Delete
End Sub
```